# Using Postman from Android Studio

Tags: android, postman, postman-mocks

I have recently learnt about [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) and it's ability to create and store GET responses from different URLs. I am trying to use this for testing an android app. Specifically I would like to:

1. Save some collections to my account via the Postman online portal.
2. Pull the response bodies into Android Studio and save as a JSON file.
3. Reference these JSON files in my unit and instrumentation test cases.

I thought there would be an api that could be added to Gradle and would allow for me to access my Postman account. However after searching on google I can't seem to find anything. Am I missing something? Is this possible or am I dreaming?